# Matching exact position in an array

Tags: c++, c-strings

I was able to create a function that searches and returns a number of matching characters in a word, but now I'm having trouble to create another function that searches if the two words matches exactly down to the position and returns the number of matches . The constraints is c-strings.
So if a word is tiny, and I entered tine, it should return 3.

The function I attached below is simply the one I was able to figure out

```
int countMatches(const char s1[], const char s2[])
{    
  char s1copy[MAXWORDLEN+1];
  strcpy(s1copy, s1);

  int nMatches = 0;

  // For every character in s2

  for (int k2 = 0; s2[k2] != '\0'; k2++)
  {
    // For every character in the copy of s1

    for (int k1 = 0; s1copy[k1] != '\0'; k1++)
    {
        // If they match, blot it out of the copy of s1
        // so it won't be matched again

        if (s1copy[k1] == s2[k2])
        {
            nMatches++;
            s1copy[k1] = '#';
            break;
        }
    }
  }
  return nMatches;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do.  Do you just want to tell how many characters match in two strings starting from the beginning of each string?

Comment: Yeah, it needs to return number of matching characters at the exact position. The function I provided was only able to get any matching letter, but not at the exact position per say.

Comment: See bolov's answer below.

Comment: @Jimmy Huang Or do you need to count common letters in two words independing on their positions in each word?

Answer (score 1):

```
int countMatches(const char s1[], const char s2[]) {
  int i = 0;
  while (s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0' && s1[i] == s2[i])
    i++;
  return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need just to count the number of initial matching characters in two words then the function can look the following way

```
size_t countMatches( const char s1[], const char s2[] )
{    
    size_t nMatches = 0;

    while ( s1[nMatches] && s1[nMatches] == s2[nMatches] ) ++nMatches;

    return nMatches;
}
```

Take into account that it is better to use for the count the type `size_t`. It is the type of the return value of standard C function `strlen`. Operator `sizeof`also yields a value of type `size_t`. And other C standard functions that accept integer values have parameters of type `size_t`.